# How to Stretch image to fit DIV size

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV of 100px height & width and I am trying to fit an image of `800x800` pixels. Initially, the image seems very small, if I increase the `min-height` and `min-width` to 200px, then it seems fine but the image location moves and from the DIV also, the DIV size is no longer 100px, the image size becomes larger. I did search before posting my question here, unfortunately, I couldn't get what I want. Thus, I am p[osting a question.

JSfiddle:

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7L3wo5q1/15/)

I have two containers, `orig` and `stretch`, I want the image to be in the center of the `stretch` DIV. However, the image moves from its position.

Note: It's not a duplicate question, because I want the image of `stretch` container of `with & height` of 200px and to be placed within the DIV container or in the center of `stretch` container. I couldn't get a solution to solve this.

Comment: Use `.stretch img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;}`

Comment: See here:http://jsfiddle.net/7L3wo5q1/18/

Comment: This is not what I want to achieve, as I mentioned earlier. I want the image to occupy all of the `DIV`. as shown in my example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7L3wo5q1/15/), the image size in `stretch` is what I want, but to be placed within the DIV container itself.

Comment: so `use background-image` (the image is strech but because the background around the shape it look like no...)

Comment: Please check now [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7L3wo5q1/29/), I used `background-image` but this time even the `DIV` size increased, that's not what I want. I only want `height & width` of the image to be of `200px` but DIV of only `100px` height & width. Again, I need to stretch the image or I want to fit the image of larger size in the 100px DIV container.